# Django MySQLdb version doesn't match _mysql version Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, django, deployment, ubuntu, mysql-python

I'm trying to get a django site deployed from a repository. I was almost there, and then changed something (I'm not sure what!!) and was back to square one.

Now I'm trying to run ./manage.py syncdb and get the following error:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 2, 'final', 0)

I've searched forums for hours and none of the solutions presented helped. I tried uninstalling and re-installing MySQL-python and upgrading it. I get the same error when trying to import it from the python command line interpreter.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What version of mysql do you have? You say you've tried uninstalling and reinstalling mysql-python, but have you tried that with mysql? When I had problems with mysqldb I had to switch mysql versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who come upon this question:

It turns out that ubuntu _mysql version was different from the one in my venv. Uninstalling that and re-installing in my venv did the trick.

Comment: How do you uninstall and reinstall _mysql? Is it the same as just reinstalling all of MySQL itself?

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem after installing mysql-python using pip.
Seems to be an error in the pip package. I solved it by pip uninstall'ing it again, after which i downloaded and installed the package manually like this:

- # download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python
- $ tar xfz MySQL-python-1.2.3.tar.gz            (replace with newest version)
- $ cd MySQL-python-1.2.3
- $ python setup.py build
- $ sudo python setup.py install