# mysqldb _mysql version trouble

Tags: python, mysql, qgis

Hi I developped a plugin for qgis in Python 2.5 under linux, now I am trying to port it in  Windows; when qgis load the plugin it raises this error:

```
ImportError: this is MySQLdb version(1,2,3,'gamma',1) but _mysql is version (1,2,3,'final',0)
```

What should I do now? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add more info? Is your plugin pure python? Have you tried reinstalling both mysql python lib and mysql binary installer?

Comment: Similar question with answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137214/django-mysqldb-version-doesnt-match-mysql-version-ubuntu).