# Django manager reveals MySQL version disagreement

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to get my current Django to work with the MySQL server I've set up for it.  I followed the instructions in djangobook and got this error:

ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 2, 'final', 0)

I followed the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137214/django-mysqldb-version-doesnt-match-mysql-version-ubuntu) answer, but got another error saying mysql-config could not be found.  Sure enough, I can't find it either.

I think the mysql version I have is older than the MySQLdb version, but have tried several ways to install MySQL 1.2.3 and nothing seems to have taken.

I'm running on Linux Mint 10 with Python 2.7.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may have been that my Mint install was bad, upon wiping my computer and installing Mint Debian the problem ceased to exist.  It might have also been that I had too many attempts at installing mysql on the computer, but I'm fairly confident the primary issue was my installer and updater being corrupted.