# I want to connect to mysql in webpy But I get this error:<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>

Tags: python, web.py

This is my code:

```
import web    
import MySQLdb
urls = ('/', 'capture')    
app = web.application(urls,globals())    
class capture:    
    def GET(self):    
        db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='mydata', user='root', pw='123456')           
if __name__ == "__main__":    
        app.run()
```

and I ran it and open localhost page and get error:

`"<type 'exceptions.ImportError'> at / this is MySQLdb version (1, 2, 4, 'beta', 4), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 3, 'final', 0)"`

How can we solve the issue.

Comment: try importing `MySQLdb`

Comment: that 's get same error:(

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137214/django-mysqldb-version-doesnt-match-mysql-version-ubuntu

Comment: tanx I solve it. I have another question. Is this code create database which name 'mydata'? or just connect to that database?

Answer (score 0):

Glad that the link helped, Regarding your second question

> db = web.database(dbn='mysql', db='mydata', user='root', pw='123456')

It only `connects` to the given `DataBase` using the given `credentials`. It is presumed the DB is already created and you are connecting that DB. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user3789719 You can consider accepting answer and upvoting if you like.. :-)